# Logstash Filter for Cisco ASA Source Destination and Communication

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, elk, grok

I want to configure logstash filter to see asa logs with communication detail.

## LOG Sample:

## Dec 27 02:48:08 Test-FW : %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 3505833084 for Test-OUT:192.168.1.10/58538 to Mgmt-IN:192.168.100.10/1159 duration 0:00:00 bytes 4153 TCP FINs from Test-OUT

Need for Below Data filter:
Source IP: 192.168.1.10
Destination IP: 192.168.100.10
Source Port: 58538
Destination Port: 1159
Source Zone: Test-OUT
Destination Zone: Mgmt-IN
Protocol: TCP
Device Name: Test-FW
Size: 4153 Bytes (Optional)

## Below configuraiton not working:

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
}
}
filter {
grok {
id => "ASA"
match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
#       add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
#       add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ] }

}
grok {
id => "ALLOW-SRC-DST"
match => { "syslog_message" => "inside:%{HOSTNAME:inside_host}/%{NUMBER:inside_port} to outside:%{HOSTNAME:outside_host}/%{NUMBER:outside_port}" }
}
#syslog_pri { }
#      date { match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
#    }
}

output {
if [@metadata][pipeline] {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
manage_template => false
index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
pipeline => "%{[@metadata][pipeline]}"
}
}
else {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
manage_template => false
index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
}
```

```
`
```

Comment: Why not use the pre-defined %{CISCOFW302013_302014_302015_302016} pattern?

Comment: The Cisco patterns are defined [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/legacy/firewalls).